# Mouse position within photoshop - extendscript

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I am trying to get the mouse position inside the photoshop canvas (I am working on an HTML5 panel for photoshop). I have searched in a different places but couldn't find the answer I am looking for.

Some show how to see the mouse position in ScriptUI, but thats not what am looking for.

I found out that there's an info panel that shows the mouse position on the canvas so I am pretty sure there's a way to access this informatio. Also I understand that you can write c++ libraries and use them inside the extendscript, so if this can be accessed that way (writing a c++ library) its also accepted.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible by any means, as far as I am aware.  May I ask what you're trying to accomplish with the mouse position?  If you're commited, you may be able to construct a gnarly hack by using Node.js to get the global mouse position or something, but if won't give you back a position relative to the overall canvas if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I was looking for the positioning of the mouse above the canvas. It would be hard determining position using the global position of the mouse on the screen.